Column formatting by elapsed time
I need to format a column in SharePoint Online with this features:
If the value in the "Ordine" column is "ASSENTE" and it has been more than 5 minutes since the record was created, the cell will be formatted in red.
If the value in the "Ordine" column is "ASSENTE" and it has been less than 5 minutes since the record was created, the cell will be formatted in orange.
If the value in the "Ordine" column is anything other than "ASSENTE", the cell will remain unaffected.
The only thing that not works is:
If the value in the "Ordine" column is "ASSENTE" and it has been more than 5 minutes since the record was created, the cell will be formatted in red.
I need some help to find the right way
Here is my JSON
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
    "background-color": "=if([$Ordine] == 'ASSENTE' && (floor(@now - Number([$Created])) / 60000) >= 5, '#FF0000', if([$Ordine] == 'ASSENTE', '#FFD700', ''))"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "[$Ordine]"
    }
  ]
}


Using the same JSON that you've posted, I'm not seeing any issue. Is the expected result as shown in the screenshot below?


Thank you for this test. I understant that if the field "Created" is hidden the JSON do not work. If "Created" is showed, the JSON works as expected.
I wonder if there is a way to handle the hidden "Created"

JSON formatting is client-side and need columns to be displayed to work.

@AndreaGail, try adding sorting/filtering or calculated column based on "Created" date in your list view and JSON based on Created column might work without showing "Created" column directly in the list view. Let me know if it works for you.
